# How to overwrite a copied rectangle instead of inserting it (which is the default behavior of yank-rectangle)?

Tags: yank, rectangle

After copying a "rectangle" using `C-x r M-w`, doing `C-x r y` yanks or pastes the rectangle. But that inserts the copied rectangle.

How can I paste the copied rectangle so that it overwrites the text?

Example:

```
 a b c d e f g
 h i j k▮l m n
 o p q r s t u▮
```

I copied the rectangle enclosed between the cursor positions shown above using `M-x copy-rectangle-as-kill` or `C-x r M-w`.

Now when I paste it in front of the character `h` using `M-x yank-rectangle` or `C-x r y`, I want the result to look like

```
 a b c d e f g
▮l m n k l m n
 s t u r s t u
```

instead of

```
 a b c d e f g
▮l m n h i j k l m n
 s t u o p q r s t u
```

How can I make the `yank-rectangle` overwrite?

Comment: Works for me. Try running Emacs with the -Q flag in order to use the default configuration.

If that works then its going to be something in your configuration.

Comment: Ah! I mistakenly asked the reverse question. I mean to find a way for `C-x r y` to overwrite. I am editing my question now.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use `M-x picture-mode`.  `C-c C-y`, bound to command `picture-yank-rectangle`, does what you want.  (You can use `C-_` to undo.)

These related keys are also available in `picture-mode`:

- `C-c C-k` - Clear a rectangle and save it (`picture-clear-rectangle`)
- `C-c C-w` - Clear a rectangle and save it in a register (`picture-clear-rectangle-to-register`)
- `C-c C-x` - Like `C-c C-y`, but uses the rectangle in a register (`picture-yank-rectangle-from-register`)
- `C-x r r` - Copy a rectangle to a register (`copy-rectangle-to-register`)

Use `C-c C-c` to exit picture mode.

You can also use the picture-mode commands without turning on `picture-mode`, but in that case their keys are not bound.  You will anyway need to load library `picture`.

So you can, for example, do this:

1. Use `C-x r r` to copy a rectangle to a register.
2. Put the cursor where you want to yank that rectangle, replacing existing text.
3. `M-x picture-yank-rectangle-from-register` (which you can also bind to a key).

Comment: Thanks! The `M-x picture-yank-rectangle-from-register` solution works great for me; I simply need to put `(require 'picture)` in my `init.el`.

Answer (score 1):

Another approach is to use `delete-selection-mode` and do this in your init file:

```
 (put 'yank-rectangle 'delete-selection 'yank)
```

But that makes `yank-rectangle` **always** replace the text at point, which might not be what you want.